# JSON Object return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is the code of jQuery that alerts `undefined`.

I need to pass the  actual_price or base_price in a variable and it gives the the desired result when I pass it like:

```
parsed.test[indx].base_price
```

Can anyone tell me how can I use this with variable?
Thanks in advance

**Example**

```
var data = '{"test":[
                 {"base_price" : "10"},
                 {"actual_price" : "20"}
               ]
        }';
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
var indx = 1;
var str = 'actual_price';
alert(parsed.test[indx].str);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need bracket notation when trying to get a property by variable:

```
alert(parsed.test[indx][str]);
```